# Z Index complexity - How to position a component inside of a div to have a higher z-index value against a component outside to its level?

Tags: css

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-01 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.section-02 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 25vh;
  left: 30vh;
}

.div-01 {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 15vh;
  left: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-01">
        Section-01
        <div class="div-01">Div-01</div>
      </section>
      <section class="section-02">
        <div>Section - 02</div>
</section>
```

I have a component like this:

```
<section id='section-01' style={{zIndex: 0}}>
    <div id='div-01' style={{zIndex: 2}}>Hello World</div>
</section>
<section id='section-02' style={{zIndex: 1}}>
</section>
```

Now my problem is that due to absolute positioning of `#section-02` and `#div-01`, `#section-02` takes the precedence and shows above `#div-01`. However I don't want that, I want `#div-01` to show up above `#section-02` and `#section-02` show up above `#section-01`.

Please note that I don't have access to alter code of `#section-01` or `#section-02`. I can only control the code of `#div-01`.

I know that if parent element has lower `z-index` then its child won't be able to show above any other entity in hierarchy of parent element and so no matter how high I set the value of `div-01` it will always show below `section-02` so I wanted to know how can I solve this problem?

Adding code sandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-flower-u5plui?file=/src/styles.css

Here's how it shows atm:
[image]

And here's how I want it to be:
[image]

Please note that you're only allowed to make changes in

```
.div-01 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 6vh;
  left: 25vh;
}
```

or in JSX part (HTML):

```
<div className="div-01">Div-01</div>
```

I don't have access to section-01 or section-02.

I cannot restructure the HTML as these comes from different App owners and I have only control to div and its inner content.

Comment: Could you please provide your css? Or even better a snippet?

Comment: Hello Max, sorry for the inconvenience, I have added extra code as you asked.

Comment: we did this at Chegg when I worked there, we used javascript to calculate the highest z-index on the page and then added 1 to it.

Comment: I can compute highest z index but that won't work as well. Look carefully, `section-01` is supposed to be below `section-02` however a child of `section-01` which is `div-01` is supposed to be above `section-02`.

Comment: Just for info. Its better practice to use snippets provided by stackoverflow since there is less chance of accidently modifying it making question unusable for future enquirers, breaking stackoverflow documentation purposes. For example code you provided already has discrepancies with your question, section-02 is set to fixed and in your question is described as absolute. Also div-01 has two position properties.

Comment: Thank you again, I have added the snippet too and would follow the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Objective

Given 2 sibling positioned elements (`.section-01` and `.section-02`), of which the first element sits at a lower stacking context than the second element. Place the child positioned element of the first element (`.section-01 > .div-01`) above the second element (`.section-02`) in the z-axis.

### Criterias

Only the child element of the first element (`.section-01 > .div-01`) may be modified by CSS (apparently by stylesheet?) and HTML (by JSX). The 2 sibling elements are generated by an app and for some reason are beyond reach (please read the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)).

Taking the aforementioned criterias into consideration, we cannot:

- add, remove, or modify HTML (`.div-01` is the exception)
- add, remove, or modify CSS (`.div-01` is the exception)

### Problem

There are two stacking contexts:

1. `.section-01` sits at `z-index: 0` without any extended positioning (<del>`top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`</del>) nor does it reference any other positioned elements (`position: relative`).
2. `.section-02` sits above everything else at `z-index: 1` and it's position references the viewport (`top`, `left`, and `position: fixed`).

Naturally #2 stacking context will occupy the foreground. Even if `.section-02` had `z-index: 0` it would still be in the foreground because in HTML layout it proceeds `.section-01`. The only way to affect stacking context is to change the element that started it (ie. `.section-01` and `.section-02`).

### Solutions

If we could just resolve this issue without having to consider the impossible restrictions mentioned under ***Criterias***, we can simply place `.section-01` back into the normal *flow* of the document by assigning it `position: static` (or removing `position:` all together), thereby removing it as an origin of a stacking context and allowing it's child element, `.div-01` to be the origin of it's own stacking context. (see **Figure I**).

**Figure I**

```
.section-01 {
  position: static;
  /* As it was originally, there was no real reason for it to have any `position` 
  property */;
}

.div-01 {
  position: fixed /* or `absolute` */;
  z-index: 2;
  /* ... */
}
```

Putting aside my doubts about the criterias being a genuine concern, (maybe it's too difficult to target the app's HTML/CSS because it assigns randomly determined #ids or .classes), there is a solution with the same result but in an indirect way.

Since the only element in our complete control is `.div-01`, we can target it's parent by using the `.has()` pseudo-class. (see **Figure II**)/

**Figure II**

```
/* This will target anything that is a direct ancestor (aka parent) of
.div-01 */
:has(> .div-01) {
  position: static
} 

.div-01 {
  position: fixed /* or absolute */;
  z-index: 2;
```

### Example

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI";
}

.section-01 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.section-02 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 30vw;
  z-index: 1;
  Width: 40vw;
  height: 30vh;
  padding: 6rem 1rem 1rem;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.div-01 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 25vw;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
}

:has(> .div-01) {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-01">
  Section-01
  <div class="div-01">Div-01</div>
</section>
<section class="section-02">
  <div>Section - 02</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explaination, while the solution you proposed would work in this case but it would nullify the z-index property of section-01. In current scenario just to make things reproducible I had these two sections however there are multiple such sections and so I wanted to know if there's a way to bring up child without altering z-index of parent. However from this I understand that its just impossible to do so so I am marking this answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

If you want div-01 to appear on top of section-02 while maintaining section-01 below both, you will need to adjust the HTML structure slightly, by adding a common index context with position relative as shown below:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.section-01 {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.section-02 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 4.6rem;
  left: 11rem;
}

.div-01 {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 2.5rem;
  left: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="section-01">
    Section-01
  </section>
  <div class="div-01">Div-01</div>
  <section class="section-02">
    <div>Section - 02</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts but this breaks the rules, I am only allowed to modify CSS and HTML of div-01 and nothing else.

Comment: Yes I saw that, the issue is that I don´t believe you can order z-index as desired without putting it in same z-index context. Given this dead end, I would center my attention on criteria's themselves trying to delimit them as rigorously as posible, making sure each one of them are actual restrictions. Simply put, in more broad context of the problem, there might be solutions we are not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the z-index of section-02 to -1 like this

```
<section id='section-02' style={{zIndex: -1}}>
</section>
```

Comment: Hello Alin, as I told I don't have access to section-02 CSS, besides the solution that you suggested won't work as it would put section-02 even before section-01